# Spring Abstract class @Autowire null while using that field in subclass constructor

Tags: spring

Following is the code:

```
public abstract class A {
    @Autowired
    public Provider provider;
}

@Component
public class B extends A {
    B() {
        provider.get();
    }
}
```

Spring is throwing `NullPointerException`, while instantiating Bean of Class B.

I know `@Autowired` defined in Abstract class are injected, but don't know in which order they are injected.

Earlier my understanding was, While instance creation of `B`, Spring will autowire fields of all subclasses and then will create instance of `B`.
But here it seems, it overlooks the subclass concept while instance creation, and just scans `B` to identify `@Autowire` field.

Comment: man, the same for me, this is annoying

Answer (score 1):

Use `@PostConstruct`. Java Object Instantiation and Spring Dependency Injection are two different flows.

```
@Component
public class B extends A {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        provider.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to call method within default constructor of B.

Comment: @geeta PostConstruct would be automatically called after constructor. Beans are not injected on constructor call time.

Answer (score 1):

If autowiring your constructors is an option the following can be helpful.

```
public abstract class A {
    protected final Provider provider;
    @Autowired
    public A(Provider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;            
    }
}

@Component
public class B extends A {
    @Autowired
    B(Provider provider) {
        super(provider);
        provider.get();
    }
}
```

Note since the latest Spring Versions you do not need to annotate the constructor with @Autowire. If you do things right the spring framework auto-detects the constructor.

Comment: true that is the resort i can go for. There are multiple subclasses extending A class. Hence i wanted to avoid constructor injection for each of the subclasses.